# Only one input value is being sent to back end?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello Im making a contact form where the inputs are being sent to a db, I have done this before in Angular and it worked with no issue, but for some reason only my name value is being sent and I'm not understanding why. It sends data to the db but only the name value, any help is appreciated.

the contact html component.

```
<form
      #contactForm="ngForm"
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm.value)"
      class="col-md-6 offset-lg-3"
    >

      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label" style="margin-top: 10%;">Name</label>
          <input

            class="form-control"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            ngModel
            required
            type="text"
          />
        </div>

        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Email</label>
          <input
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            ngModel
            required
            type="text"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label">Message</label>
          <!--<input type="text" formControlName="message" />-->
          <textarea
            class="form-control"
            cols="8"
            id="message"
            name="message"
            ngModel
            required
            rows="3"

          ></textarea>
        </div>
```

the contact.ts component

```
 onSubmit(messageData: ContactModel) {
    this.contactService.createAndStorePost(messageData.name, messageData.email, messageData.message);
    

  }
```

heres the contact service.ts

```
createAndStorePost(name: string, email: string, message: string) {
    const messageData: ContactModel = {name: name, email: email, message: message}
    this.http.post('removed the url for this post',
      messageData
    ).subscribe(responseData => {
      console.log(responseData)
    })

  }
```

the conctact.model.

```
export interface ContactModel {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  message: string;
  id?: string;


}
```

Edit: still stuck

Comment: Did you try to console log messageData just before you sent it?

Comment: name logs the value, email and message both log undefined.